# Spotting the matrix representation of the quantum AND operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

[https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~csxam/teaching/qc2020/lecturenotes.pdf](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ecsxam/teaching/qc2020/lecturenotes.pdf)

> Applying the above construction to AND we get the map $(x1,x2,y) \rightarrow (x1,x2,y⊕(x1∧x2))$ for $x1,x2,y \in \{0,1\}$.  The unitaryoperator which implements this is then simply the map $|x1〉|x2〉|y> \rightarrow |x1〉|x2〉|y \oplus (x1∧x2)〉$.

> Written as a matrix with respect to the computational basis this is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0  
\end{bmatrix}$$

How can you just spot what the matrix is with respect to the computational basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column of a quantum gate can be interpreted as the result from feeding in one of the standard 0-1 configurations of your system of qubits.

For example, the configuration corresponding to the $5$th column is $|101\rangle$ (since $5$ is $101$ in binary), so that $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$, $y = 1$. With that, we see that the corresponding output should be
$$
|x_1 \rangle |x_2 \rangle |y \oplus (x_1 \land x_2) \rangle = 
|1 \rangle |0 \rangle |1 \oplus (1 \land 0) \rangle = |101\rangle.
$$
This is represented by the vector with a $1$ in the $5$th spot and $0$s elsewhere.

Repeat this for the remaining columns. In other words, finding the matrix associated with the gate is as easy as filling out a truth table.

In this case, we could save a bit of time if we notice that the input remains unchanged except in the case where $x_1 = x_2 = 1$, which tells us that we must have a leading identitity matrix up until the bottom right $2 \times 2$ corner.